# Tableau Wildcard filter error: Function lower may give a 128010-octet result; the limit is 65000 octets error

Tags: wildcard, tableau-api, vertica

When creating a wildcard filter in Tableau with connection to a Vertica DB, I get the following error:

Function lower may give a 128010-octet result; the limit is 65000 octets error.

It seems like a problem on Vertica side but 65000 is the max size of varchar data type in Vertica.

I checked that the wildcard filter works fine with a usual Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the data is in UTF-8 format. There may be special characters in the string.

You can verify that all of the string-based data in the table is in UTF-8 format by using the [ISUTF8](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/ISUTF8.htm) function.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I only wanted the first few characters so this worked for me:

```
select upper(substring(columnname, 0, 10)) from tablename;
```

it is not a solution if you want the whole value, you need to figure something out, as the length of some value of the result might be exceeding the limit.